# When is the earliest Nunu can solo Dragon or duo Baron?

Tags: league-of-legends

If you're looking to just build Nunu for early objective sneaking/control. What are the items and skill levels needed to solo dragon or duo baron with an adc(this assumes no enemy team involvement of course), without any aggro handoffs.

This question stems from a statement made by Jatt in a Curse game in the final superweek of summer split(forget which in particular). The team was falling behind and instead of contesting dragon, Jatt recommended sneaking baron because they had a Nunu. Also showed up every once in awhile in OGN.

I changed the question to duo baron, but in reality for a Nunu to tank baron solo or in a group of 5 there are still minimum item/level requirements.

I'm looking for something like:

- You should have items x,y,z(assuming normal item build paths, nothing crazy)
- With at least 3 points in consume
- And be level 11 with dragon(or baron) being under level x

I want to know key level/item signs(a checklist perhaps) to look for/tell me I can go for certain objectives on Nunu.

Comment: As a side note, I think that having blue would be super important for this. I also doubt you can solo baron with Nunu in a reasonable timeframe, but that's just conjecture.

Comment: There is a huge difference between soloing and tanking, and between dragon and baron. Also all of these questions would need quite a lot of information in their answers. I VTC on this as too broad but I'd gladly retract my CV as soon as the question is narrowed down to be more specific.

Comment: this depends so much: your team items, enemie team items, vision, level advantage, currently dead players, minutes in the game, ... simply everything.

Comment: @Jutschge solo and duo are pretty similar time frames/item requirements

Comment: @PhilippSander if you read everything I stated assuming no enemy involvement

Comment: @Brian Well not for nunu ;). If you effectively want to solo Baron an AD Bruiser build would be better than a tank build which would be alot better for duoing it. And Dragon requires completely different items again. It's an interesting question but i think it would be better if it was spilt up into multiple ones.

Comment: @Jutschge editted but I would disagree CDR and AP along with tankyness is better than AD(no benefit to consume heal or skill damage output) for early objective control. I have a general idea to the answer I'm looking for but want to make sure I am not missing anything

Comment: @Brian well as I said it requires a lot of explanation. But the question looks a lot better now :) and it doesn't need a 20 page long answer anymore ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't itemize just for dragon/baron control**, because you'll think you're doing it sneaky, having warded and dewarded around drake and doing it solo jungler, but if the enemy team/jungler guesses it **your itemisation won't help much in a smite fight**.

**Nunu can solo drake from lvl 6 onwards**, if you're willing to use your ult to get some of that huge dmg that would be too long to do over time, because E is not so good as a damaging spell (cooldownwise, else it's a good spell in a burst combo). His Q is of course very good, but the CD is way too long, and I'd suggest you keep it for doublesmiting Drake or Baron.

**I'd never solo Baron as Nunu**, even in a bot game when you're super fed, because that's something only AD hypercarries can do, like Master Yi and ADs with insane sustain.
Duo Baron with hypercarry like Vayne can work very well because Nunu tanks well and can boost AS. It should work any time from mid game onwards if you or your carry aren't so far behind. But always keep in mind that the presence/absence of the ADC and his last seen position are the more important pieces of information for the enemy team.

**Do a AP/tanky build**, get *Spirit of the Spectral Wraith* early. The equilibrium between AP and tanky will depend on enemy team comp and yours, if you lack APCs, get some AP and play sneakier to get those ult traps that can turn games at lower elos. I'd personnally get mega tanky items that allow me to reach the **40% CDR cap** that's very important to keep your carry on steroids and perma-slow an enemy. That and of course, great sustain and Q buffs easily, and ult available every fight or so.

Comment: I'd like to add that it's perfectly viable to focus the first item or 2 into AP/CDR in order to attempt to solo dragon easily and grab pinks.  If you ward the enemy jungle a bit and know where their jungler is you can go for the  dragon soon as they are far enough away.  From there you'd definitely want to build support into more of a utility/tank bot.

Answer (score 0):

Couple month ago Nunu was required to have lvl 5 for his Consume, Spirit of the Elder Lizard and cap for CDR. All 3 elements of criteria is possible at 15 minutes when baron spawns, so Nunu was able to do it right avay constantly healing himself through bites and doing decent damage.
With recent changes it's become way more difficult to solo monster objectives, so i would not recommend it nowadays.